# How to implement list of names into a pre-made class?

Tags: python, list, class, object

I have a class called Name that takes first and last name with few basic functions:

```
class Name:

def __init__(self, first, last):
    self._first = first
    self._last = last

def first(self):
    return self._first

def last(self):
    return self._last

def __repre__(self):
    print("{} {}".format(self._first, self._last))
```

Now I need to create a function that takes a list that returns a list of Name objects. 
Text_file is just a text file that has names line by line with a space between first and last name.

```
def name_list(text_file):

  with open(text_file) as f:
      lines = f.read().splitlines()
      for name in lines:
          print(lines)
```

I realize I've only taken the list and returned the names in the list, not a list as Name objects.

How do I use my class to return a list of name objects?

Comment: Style tip: Your `first` and `last` methods are redundant.  Python frowns on getters and setters and instead encourages you to access attributes directly.  Just do `self.first = first` and `self.last = last` inside the `__init__` method and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def name_list(text_file):
    file = open(text_file, 'r')
    list = []
    for line in file:
        first, last = line.split()
        list.append(Name(first, last))
    return list
```

This will loop through each line, break it up on the space, create a name object, add it to the list, then return the list.

Then to print it out do something like:

```
list = name_list(file)
for name in list:
    print('Name: {0} {1}'.format(name._first, name._last))
```

Comment: As far as my code being redundant, how should I do it instead? In our class we were taught to use "._" in the constructor, should I not be using getters and setters? If so why not?

Comment: While that wasn't me who said that, python has no way of hiding class members (at least that I'm aware of).  So people will use the '_' to say that this variable is private and shouldn't be modified outside of the setter method.  So in Python, from what I've gathered, we just use members directly and don't use setters and getters since there's no such thing as a 'private' variable.

So instead of using the Last and First functions you have, you should just use the members directly such as in my example.  If you do that, I recommend removing the underscores.

Comment: @AlexLee - [Here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/01/why-dont-you-want-getters-and-setters.html) is a great article on why getters and setters are ugly in Python. Basically, they serve no purpose. As RNikoopour said, a user can still alter `self._first` directly and completely bypass your methods. So, all they do is make the code bloated, harder to follow, and less efficient. Also, they undermine Python's principle of *"we are all consenting adults"*; a user *should* be allowed to alter whatever attributes they please. Trying to hide them behind methods is unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is just to split each line on white space. You've got some redundant stuff in the above: you can simply iterate on a file to go line by line in it -- no need to call readlines.

```
def name_list(text_file):
    names = []
    with open(text_file) as f:
        for line in f:
             first_name, last_name in line.split(' ')  # tuple unpacking
             names.append(Name(first_name, last_name))
    return names
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought it might be cool to show how to do this as a one-liner in Python. I understand it might be a bit less-readable to newcomers and, therefore, probably shouldn't be the accepted answer, but worth knowing:

```
>>> names = [Name(*line.split()) for line in open(text_file)]
```

Basically, we iterate through each line in the text file, splitting on whitespace, then we use the `*`-operator to unpack the values as positional arguments to the class.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution:

```
name_objects = list()
with open(text_file) as f:
      for each_line in f:
          name_objects.append(Name(each_line.split()))
```